# How to trigger long-press (click-and-hold) on mobile devices with Vue / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is only on Mobile devices. It works as intended on desktop, so I'll omit all those styles and functionality.

I have a Vue-component like this:

**Template**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="invisible-overlay-styles">
    <button
      v-if="! videoIsPlaying"
      @click="playVideo()"
      @mousedown="playVideo()"
    >
    </button>

    <a
      v-if="videoIsPlaying"
    >
    </a>
  </div> <!-- invisible-overlay-styles -->

  <video ... /> 

</div>
```

All the divs, buttons, anchors and videos are stacked on top of one-another, using `display: block` and `position: absolute; width: 100%; etc. etc. etc.`

**Method**

```
  playVideo(){
    console.log( 'Im playing!!' );
    if( this.player ){
      if( this.player.paused ){
        this.player.play()
      }
    }
  }
```

If i click it, it works as it should:

- On the first click, the video plays.
- On the second click, the link is clicked.

But if I click-and-hold, then neither `@click` nor `@mousedown` is triggered. This is both in:

- Chrome on my Samsung Android-device
- On Safari on my iPhone 7
- In iOS Simulator on my Mac.
  ... I've checked, and no console.logs occur, when I click-and-hold (long-press).

---

So two questions:

1. I get why `@click` isn't triggered, since that's a combination of `@mousedown` and `@mouseup`. But why doesn't `@mousedown` get triggered, when I long-press?
2. How do I target long-press on mobile devices using Vue (or JavaScript)?

Comment: You'll need to use touch events such as `touchstart` and `touchend`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT: Dec 2022**

[`PointerEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events) is the recommended way now as it covers all devices:

```
<button
  v-if="!videoIsPlaying"
  @pointerdown="playVideo()"
></button>
```

To read a long-press:

```
<template>
  <button
    @pointerdown="isHolding = true"
    @pointerup="isHolding = false"
  ></button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const isHolding = ref(false);
</script>
```

---

**ORIGINAL:**

You'll need to use either the [TouchEvent API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent) or the [PointerEvent API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent).

The browser compatibility for both is good:

- https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_touchevent
- https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_pointerevent

They each have similar events to the MouseEvent API, i.e. `touchstart` = `mousedown`.

I've personally found TouchEvents better than PointerEvents, but, you might have to do some testing to see which is best in your case.

---

So, as you can guess with Vue, you can use `@touchstart`:

```
<button
    v-if="!videoIsPlaying"
    @click="playVideo()"
    @mousedown="playVideo()"
    @touchstart="playVideo()"
/>
```

---

If you want to determine it as a long-press, you'll have to store a value on `touchstart` and change it on `touchend`:

```
<button
    @touchstart="touching = true"
    @touchend="touching = false"
/>
...
data() {
    return {
        touching: false
    }
}
```

Comment: I just played around with this some more. The problem with this is, that if I click-and-drag (scrolling), where the initial click is on this element, then the `@touchstart` is triggered. Are there a way to disregard these?

Comment: Really depends on your use case. If you have a condition to base it off, you can

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `@contextmenu.prevent="func"`. This worked for me when I hold on an element from phone. But, works like a right click.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).